# Background Image Not Showing In Header

Tags: html, css, pug, stylus

CSS Background image not showing. heres my stylus file for the heading section:

```
.header {
  height 50vh
  border-bottom 5px solid #34495E
  background url(img/head.png) no-repeat center center fixed
  background-size cover
}
.nav {
  display flex
  align-items center
  justify-content flex-end
  padding 1em
  background rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
  position fixed
  top 0
  left 0
  width 100%
  z-index 5
}
.nav-item {
  list-style none
  display inline
  padding 1em
}
a {
  text-decoration none
  color #ececec
  transition 1s
  padding-right 1em
}
a:hover {
  color darken(#ececec, 25%)
  text-decoration underline
}
.space {
  content " "
  height 3.0625em
}
```

This is what it looks like:
[image: swe]

This is the image that is supose to be the background for the header(The white section with Darcey Mckelvey in it):

[image: head]

Comment: The URL works and eveything and its all set up properly I tested that.

Comment: could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @DavidAnderton can't I have it written in jade and stylus, to much effort to convert.

Comment: Is the img folder in the same location as the css file because the path you have is relative to the location of the css file. The usual setup would require the path ../img/head.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the height for the header class.

```
   .header {
   border-bottom: 5px solid #34495E;
   background: url('img/head.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   }
```

Comment: For some odd reason I took the height away but the height stayed the same, thus nothing happened. No show for the image still.

Comment: That's weird. it works perfectly fine in jsFiddle.    https://jsfiddle.net/5ajp38vm/

Comment: I figured it out I had a dive on top of the header that I didn't add to the code snippet above that was pushing it down.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try putting a width into your .header? say:

```
.header{
    width:100%
}
```